# Horizontally align carousel control in center?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Framework: bootstrap 3

I want to align carousel controls in center horizontally just like in the following image:

[image]

Here is my html code for carousel

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <h3><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></button>Lorel Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
                ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <h3><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></button>Lorel Ipsum 2</h3>
            <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
                ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Prev</button>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this class on the outer div

```
.centerAlign{
    width: 400px; //some width you want
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto; //to align in center
    display: table;
}
```